# Excel 2019: how to count cells in a non-contiguous Named Range

Tags: excel, function, count

I have a Named Range that consists of multiple areas, ie, the range is non-contiguous. I can select the range and in the Watch window of the VB Editor  type **? Selection.Cells.Count** to get the number of cells in the Named Range.

However, there is no such easy function in Excel itself. **COUNTA** gives me the number of non-empty cells, but **COUNTIF** and **COUNTBLANK** return an error with non-contiguous ranges. Can anyone recommend a solution (**non-VBA**)?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: try to do the same (formula) in Office 365 online..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but is not a good solution:
Assuming the range is called MultiArea and contains 3 areas;
AREAS(MultiArea) returns 3
COUNTA(Multiarea) counts all the non-blank cells
COUNTBLANK(INDEX(MultiArea,,,1)) counts the blank cells in the first area
so this gives the answer you are looking for
=COUNTA(MultiArea)+COUNTBLANK(INDEX(MultiArea,,,1))+COUNTBLANK(INDEX(MultiArea,,,2))+COUNTBLANK(INDEX(MultiArea,,,3))

Comment: Thanks, Charles. It isn't overly elegant, but it does work. Strange that there's no simple function for this...